# Covering a rectangular board with T shaped tetramonoes

Tags: combinatorics

I vaguely remember that the following problem appeared in the AMM around 1965 in its section of Mathematical Problems and Solutions. (I think it
was an elementary problem.)

A rectangular m x n board can be covered with T-tetraminoes if and only if both m and n are multiples of 4.

Normally, the solution should have appeared after a few months. But as I recall, when it was due, there was a comments that the full solution had been published earlier, possibly in AMM itself.

Having access to old issues of AMM is not easy. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: A quick Google search yielded https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313337

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964613/calculating-invariant-for-t-shape-tetrominos-on-rectangular-board